# How to access local CD drive in Teamviewer?

Tags: compact-disc, teamviewer

When in a TeamViewer session, how can I access my computer's CD drive from the remote computer?

Comment: The same way you would without teamviewer? Via Explorer?

Comment: @DaveRook: I assumed he wants to access the CD drive of the source machine in the target/remote session.

Comment: CJ7, you really need to explain what you mean then - are you trying to access files on a CD/DVD or stream some form of media from the CD/DVD? I would be amazed if you can get the later to work!

Comment: @DaveRook: All I want to do is access the CD drive of the local computer from within a Teamviewer session.

Comment: @CJ7 which computer is "local" in your question? The one you're working on or the remote one? Please edit your question to be more clear.

Comment: @gronostaj: the local computer is the computer that is not the remote computer

Comment: @CJ7 I've edited your question. In the future please be more specific and check if your question isn't unclear or confusing before posting. If anybody suggests your question isn't clear and requests additional information, you should consider editing it yourself to clarify it. We may try to help you, but we have to know what exactly is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let me get this right... your local computer (PC-A) is doing TeamViewer session to remote computer (PC-B), and from PC-B you wanted to access the content of CD/DVD Drive of PC-A?

(If the above assumption is correct)

There is no exact way of doing it. But there is a workaround.

If all you need is PC-B (remote PC) to have the files in the CD/DVD of PC-A (local PC), then after you open session to PC-B, use the TeamViewer File Transfer facility, and simply start transferring your files from your PC-A to PC-B.

Hope this helps.